# How to hide {{title}} in <title> tag while using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to dynamically update the `<title>` of my page based on which route / page a user is viewing. Problem is, when the page loads,  for a few seconds it shows {{title}} inside my `<title>` tag where it later puts in the title of the current page (loaded from the controller). Any way I could have the {{title}} hidden by default until the value is loaded?

Comment: Use [ng-cloak][http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak] it works for body not sure if it will work for head section

Comment: ngCloak is a CSS trick, and will not work in the `<title>` element.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use `ngBind` on the `<title>` element:

```
<title ng-bind="title"> Default title </title>
```

Comment: Thanks. One more thing, in my controller I need to put the title on $rootScope in order for it to show in the <title>, may be because I'm using ng-view on a div later and the controller is limited to it. Is there any other way to have the controller set it for the whole page?

Comment: KNow this is old, but you can just set an "ng-controller" attribute on the html element of your page.

Comment: This is THE answer. The title specified inside the tag works as "placeholder" and when Angular is loaded, it is replaced by the expression in the ng bind. In my case I have a title like "My Site" and ng-bind is "'My Site - ' + controller.page" and it works flawlessy!

Comment: @duskwuff `ng-bind` doesn't work. Do I need to do anything else? I am setting the title dynamically through a rootScope var: `<title ng-bind="mytitle"> {{ mytitle }} </title>` but it still momentarily shows {{ mytitle }}

Comment: found out why - the main js file (loading Angular) wasn't loaded in HEAD, rather at the bottom of the index.html file

Comment: @Growler The contents of the `<title>` tag should be a placeholder title, not `{{ title }}`.