# Why is it that I see {{ ... }} before loading in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, partial-views

Do you know why is the `{{ project.title }}` before I see the real value of the scope.

And how to solve that ?

**EDIT : `<title>{{ pageTitle }}</title>`**

Page is loading

[image]

Page completely loaded

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `<title ng-bind="pageTitle"></title>`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide {{title}} in <title> tag while using AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051292/how-to-hide-title-in-title-tag-while-using-angularjs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your views for Angular.JS apps are just static HTML. If you remove the script tag that references Angular.JS, you'd end up with a page full of curly brackets in plain sight that never get replaced.

When your browser finished loading Angular.JS and loading your application, the expressions in those curly brackets are evaluated. That's why you see, for a brief moment, `{{…}}` in your page title.

As noted by others, the [`ng-cloak` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) is usually the way to get rid of the flickering before the app is fully loaded.

But since `ng-cloak` is just CSS, it cannot be applied to the page title. You'll need **ng-bind** for that, as [noted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18051435/473467).

```
<title ng-bind="pageTitle">Default Title</title>
```

Comment: `ng-cloak` does not work on title. You'll need `ng-bind` for that. Otherwise good explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You should be showing the code, but in general it's probably because you aren't using `ng-cloak` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak
However, in the case of the title, you need to use `ng-bind=project.title` instead `<title>{{ project.title }}</title>`

Check [How to hide {{title}} in <title> tag while using AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051292/how-to-hide-title-in-title-tag-while-using-angularjs)

Comment: So this is actually a duplicate? ;-)

Comment: looks like. I realised it when you pointed out that ngcloak might not work on the title element

Answer (score 1):

To prevent this, you should use ng-bind instead of {{ }} for the first screen of your app.
ng-bind is a directive that is added to an element attribute, so it is displayed only when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

According to the description of [ngBind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind), we usually use `{{ expression }}` to replace ng-bind. But in a first-loading situation, image that you firstly load AngularJS(maybe in index.html), it'll show the original {{ }}. After that, it transits to what u need. To overcome it, you can use ngCloak or just use ng-bind in your first page.

OK, please check [this](https://gist.github.com/vojtajina/1022724) ?