# Angular template still flashes after adding ng-cloak and necessary sass

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an app using Angular 1.x and want to use a constant in my JS file to represent the page title.

Testing locally, despite adding `ng-cloak` with [recommended css](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak), `{{ default_title }}` still flashes before the title is actually set.

My css is being loaded first in the `<head>`, followed by `<title>`, then JavaScript. I can see my styles are in the page source css.

What else do I need to add to prevent this from happening?

index.html:

```
<title ng-if="connectionStatus" ng-cloak>{{ default_title }}</title>
```

defaults.scss:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi, when is angularJS loaded? If it's not try and load it there. If that fails try and add the class to the element like `class="ng-cloak"`

Comment: Take into consideration that if `default_title` isn't ready yet it won't be shown (cause ng-cloak), so, the `title` property of the page is not set and by default the web browser renders the url until there is a `title`. Is this the "flashes" you see?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide {{title}} in <title> tag while using AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051292/how-to-hide-title-in-title-tag-while-using-angularjs)

Comment: @Beofett I've tried `<title ng-bind="mytitle"> {{ mytitle }} </title>` with `$rootScope.mytitle` but it still shows the template {{ mytitle }} briefly in the title before Angular rootScope is loaded

Comment: @Growler I believe the problem is that the `title` tag is loaded before the Angular library, because `<title>` is in the head. What that answer is suggesting is that you put a default title, because there is no way to apply ng-cloak to the `title` tag as it relies on CSS styling, which aren't valid for head element tags.  E.g. instead of `<title ng-bind="mytitle"> {{ mytitle }} </title>`, try `<title ng-bind="mytitle"> ...loading page title</title>`, or something similar. Once Angular loads, "...loading page title" will be replaced with the value of `rootScope.mytitle`.